# How to load data from a .csv file without importing the .csv module/library

Tags: python, csv

```
def loadfunc(filestr):
listoftuples = []
listofnumbers = []
tupleinlist = []
with open(filestr, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for item in line:
            if item.isdigit():
                listofnumbers.append(float(item))
            else:
                word = item
tupleinlist.append(word)
tupleinlist.append(listofnumbers)
listoftuples.append(tuple(tupleinlist))
return listoftuples
print(listoftuples)
```

Above is my code. So the requirement is to load data from a .csv file and into a list of tuples. The data in the file is something like:

```
 - apple    23.2    24.3    25.6
 - banana   22.1    20.0    19.9
```

Withing each tuple in the list it has to be `(word, listoffloats)` so the list would look like:

```
[(apple, [23.2, 24.3, 25.6]), (banana, [22.1, 20.0, 219.9])]
```

But with my code it screws this up and doesn't return it because when it iterates over "item" in each "line", it iterates over each character (like `.`, `a`, `p`, `p`, `l`, `e`) rather than item being things like `apple`, `23.2`, etc.

Help please I don't know how to fix this and no it is not allowed to use csv libraries/modules for this tutorial.

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable name, you're overwriting the built in `file` function when you do that and it might cause trouble.

Answer (score 5):

Lets say you have the data in t.csv. You can hold the data in a `results` list, then use `split` on each line in the file and append the results of your split to `results`. Using the csv module would have done this for you, but you can replicate the delimiter behaviour with `split`.

```
with open('t.csv', 'r') as f:
    results = []
    for line in f:
            words = line.split(',')
            results.append((words[0], words[1:]))
    print results
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the input file contains input like

```
# in.txt
# apple 23.2 24.3 25.6
# banana 22.1 20.0 19.9
# end
from collections import defaultdict

def get_word_float(infile_str):
    d = defaultdict(list)
    with open(infile_str) as inf:
        for l in inf:
            item = l.split() # split by space             
            d[item[0]].extend(map(float, item[1:]))
    return d

print(get_word_float('in.txt'))

# defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'apple': [23.2, 24.3, 25.6], 'banana': [22.1, 20.0, 19.9]})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('a.csv', 'r') as f:
    #read from csv line by line, rstrip helps to remove '\n' at the end of line
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f] 

results = []
for line in lines:
    words = line.split(',')#get each item in one line
    listOfFloat = map(float,words[1:])# convert string to float
    tup = (words[0],listOfFloat)
    results.append(tup)
print results
```