# How to take data from a csv file and make it into a python dictionary without importing anything

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to take data from a csv file and make it into a dictionary without importing anything(such as the csv module or pandas modules that help with reading csv files.). The data is:

```
area_fips   own_code    industry_code     total_annual_wages
     1000          0                10            4820416591
     1001          5                22             776481288
     1002         10               441              12102645
```

so I need the output to look like this:

`{'area_fips': '1000', 'own_code': '0', 'industry_code': '10', 'total_annual_wages': '4820416591'}`

`{'area_fips': '1001', 'own_code': '5', 'industry_code': '22', 'total_annual_wages': '776481288'}`

`{'area_fips': '1002', 'own_code': '10', 'industry_code': '441', 'total_annual_wages': '12102645'}`

This has got me confused because I know how to use csv.dictreader(which will give an output exactly like how I need it to), but we aren't allowed to import anything.

Comment: but we aren't allowed to import anything  - What do you mean by that?

Comment: I cannot import any modules such as the csv module.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load data from a .csv file without importing the .csv module/library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32327936/how-to-load-data-from-a-csv-file-without-importing-the-csv-module-library)

Comment: Have you looked at the code for `csv.dictreader`? It's in `\lib\csv.py`.

Comment: I have but its still a little confusing how to go about coding this. I am still relatively new to programming.